# Updating Textmate's Markdown Bundle URL Regex

Tags: regex, textmate, markdown

Hey all, I'm looking to do pretty much what the title says. As-is, the seemingly favored [Textmate Markdown bundle](https://github.com/textmate/markdown.tmbundle) chokes on some URLs. What I'd like to do is implement [@diegoperini's pattern](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) to properly match URLs.

Some problems on my end: I suck with Regular Expressions, and I've never edited a Textmate bundle.

I'm not sure how to even explain what I'm trying. So essentially what I'm looking for is someone to point me in the right direction and help me along in getting this sorted out, and learn a bit more about Textmate and regex along the way.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

- I like to use Rubular.com for learning and testing Regex.
- You want to use the Bundle Editor.

  - Read [this.](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles)
  - Check out [Textmate Screencasts](http://macromates.com/screencasts).
  - You could also buy the [Peepcode screencast on Textmate](https://peepcode.com/products/textmate-for-rails-2). It has some info about bundle editing that may be useful, although there's not huge amounts on what you want.
  - There is also [a book](http://pragprog.com/book/textmate/textmate)

Good luck!